# How to use titanium inspector using titanium 5.2.2?

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

I am using Appcelerator titanium CLI to build ios app. I want to debug the app With Chrome DevTools but it seems like it's not compatible with the version which I have installed currently.
As per ti-inspector documentation, I have installed the node package by the below command.

```
npm install -g ti-inspector
```

So, When I tried this into my titanium project directory I am getting this response which is unexpected.

```
tn-inspector

Unexpected error: undefined
```

NOTE: titanium version - 5.2.2

Useful GitHub link: https://github.com/omorandi/TiInspector

Need help to understand or mitigate this issue. Thanks in advance!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That repo is 5 years old and might not be compatible with the current SDK. You can use this instruction: https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Appcelerator_Studio_allOS_en/page/debugging_android_apps_with_3rd-party_tools.html to use the internal dev tools connection.

Comment: Do I need to connect an android device to my system?

Comment: no, you can use an emulator too. Just like you would without the debugger (`-T emulator`)